# S3CMD timed out

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, centos, s3cmd

I'm trying to create a good script to backup my files into `Amazon S3` storage service.
With that in mind, I'm using the `s3cmd` tool, which seem very useful for that.
But one thing is bothering me tough.
Sometimes when I'm uploading a file it gives me the follow message error:

```
s3cmd sync --skip-existing -r --check-md5 -p -H --progress ./files/ s3://company-backup/files/
./files/random-file.1 -> s3://company-backup//files/random-file.1  [1 of 11]
  3358720 of 14552064    23% in   10s   299.86 kB/s  failed
WARNING: Upload failed: ./files/random-file.1 (timed out)
WARNING: Retrying on lower speed (throttle=0.00)
WARNING: Waiting 3 sec...
```

So looking on the internet I found out [this post](http://sumanrs.wordpress.com/2013/03/19/s3cmd-timeout-problems-moving-large-files-on-s3-250mb/), which basically says to increase the `socket_timeout` in the configuration file, but how I can figure out the best `timeout` to many different size of files ?
I mean, sometimes I would need to send `100MB` and others times `10GB`. And the worst thing is that when the connection is closed by the `timeout`, it tries to send the file again but it don't start from where stop it, but, start all over again, I really need to avoid that.
So two questions here:

1- how know the best `socket_timeout` value

2- how keep my uploading from where it stop it ? (in cases when it gives timeout)

Comment: I found this while looking around http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657187/how-to-upload-to-s3-with-pause-resume-support . See if it gives u a clue for problem 2

Answer (score 1):

Answering the 2nd part of the questions. The new version of s3cmd supports a [`--continue` parameter](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/issues/280) on gets and puts.