# How resume file while uploading to server

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services

in my project user want to upload 3GB video file.
in case while uploading time it stopped because of some internet failure or any other disturbance.

while next uploading time it should start from where it got stopped.
it should not start from stating point again.

any suggestions please....

it's a .net project (MVC,Jquery,EF and Sql server)

i am storing all files into AWS s3.

Comment: This is very far from a trivial problem to solve. You need to upload and save the file as chunks so that when the request is 'paused' (which means it's actually completely aborted) you need to store the file in its partial state. You can then resume when needed with the next chunk. No one here is going to write this code for you so I'd suggest you do some research. [This](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/04/resumeupload/) is an example in PHP which can be translated relatively easily.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a starting point ,,,

Source; [How to upload to S3 with Pause/Resume support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657187/how-to-upload-to-s3-with-pause-resume-support)

I implemented the following app.

Github Link: https://github.com/interpegasus/condo_example
It is based on the sample app and gem from: http://cotag.github.com/Condominios/

All credit to https://github.com/cotag/ for a great gem and work.

FEATURES:

- Pause / Resume support ~ 5MB chunks
- Large File Upload
- Progress Bar
- No Java Applet / No Flash
- Registration system via devise

Comment: hi i tried this , how to implement that in asp.net mvc project

Comment: sorry i am not getting ,please help me the sample

Comment: please help with the sample or steps